# Кто управляет деятельностью разработчика?

Tags: любой-язык

У меня такой вопрос. Я junior и в организации ко мне приставили менеджера, который мной управляет. До этого в организациях мной всегда управлял лид (технический специалист), но не менеджер и я не знаю, как оно должно быть в нормальной фирме, возможно, ориентируясь на зарубежные фирмы.

Она мне диктует, сколько я должна тратить время на изучение технического задания, какие вопросы и в какой форме я должна задавать. Например, она сказала, что рассказ о проекте, где я буду работать, идёт 15 минут. Хотя за 15 минут там точно не разберёшься, потому что техническое задание размытое. Потом, чтоб я не задавала вопросы, она сказала в письменной форме их подготовить, хотя по Скайпу это все намного быстрее.

Потом она мне указывает, что, когда мне дают задачу, то вопросы по ней я должна задать сразу, хотя у меня вопросы могут возникнуть по мере выполнения задачи.
Затем на аттестации она дала мне характеристику.

Я не понимаю, почему этим не занимается технический специалист, что может знать экономист в технической части? Вообще это правомерно, что менеджер пишет мне характеристику и даёт мне рекомендации?
Скажите, пожалуйста, как оно должно быть?

Comment: должно быть не так, можете начинать искать другую организацию

Comment: просто делайте то, что вам говорят. вы же джун, изучайте, пытайтесь разобраться. полгода вам точно на раскачку дадут. сейчас новая реальность наступила, никто больше с вами сидеть рядом не будет.

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "правомерно" ? В трудовом кодексе об этом не сказано кто кем должен руководить и какие у него должны быть компетенции. Везде по разному. Да, очевидно, что в вашей компании просто нет технических специалистов, которые могли бы выполнять такую работу. И да, такой стиль руководства явно усложняет процесс разработки и делает его не эффективным. Если остаетесь работать в этой компании, то ищите общий язык с руководителем, объясняйте, какие требования и почему выполнены быть не могут, при этом предлагайте свое видение рабочего процесса

Comment: @Mike к сожалению, они гнут свою линию и не принимают во внимание мои аргументы или могут вообще врать, что-то придумывать просто чтобы мне препятствовать и делать как они хотят. Я боюсь, что в другой организации будет также, что на потребности работника все равно, раз они начальники, то учитывается только их мнение, которое они даже честно не высказывают. Вот поэтому я и спросила во всех ли это так организациях? Они ещё любят говорить на мои аргументы "что ты разбираешься, иди работай".

Comment: "Я боюсь, что в другой организации будет также, ... Вот поэтому я и спросила во всех ли это так организациях?" - вам уже ответили - везде по-разному. Вы же уже по своему опыту это знаете. Если в этой организации не так как в предыдущих, то почему в следующей должно быть так же как в этой? Может быть будет так же, а может и нет. В любом случае заранее узнать как будет в следующей организации не получится - чтобы заранее знать, нужны обладать навыками провидца. "что ты разбираешься, иди работай" - очевидный ответ на такой выпад - потому что это ваша работа разбираться)

Comment: Ну раз вы пишите "до этого в организациях мной всегда управлял лид", то странно, зачем вы спрашиваете вопрос по организации в других компаниях. Разработчиком управляет его непосредственный начальник, а кого в организации назначат в начальники зависит исключительно от высшего руководства. В нормальной иерархии ИТ компании это как правило тимлид.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_manager#Software_project_manager

Comment: @Alex Krass да, я работала в других фирмах. Но они были не очень. Там даже аналитика не было, никаких менеджеров. Мне казалось, что это более или менее приличная фирма в моем городе.

Comment: Как правило за джунов и мидлов отвечать должны тимлид (или начальник отдела) или кто-то из старших коллег по его распоряжению, и в случае конфликтных ситуаций они должны их разруливать. Тут вопрос, кто ваш прямой начальник по документам и к кому вы устраивались. Менеджер как правило стоит сбоку, он может чего-то там требовать, но общение с ним не носит обязательств подчиненный-исполнитель (в компаниях он не прямой руководитель), хотя и может так показаться. У вас может быть и не так. Другие разработчики в команде есть? пробовали с ними общаться?

Comment: @Alex Krass Проблема в том, что проекты там постоянно меняются и лиды на них тоже. Когда я спрашивала, кто мой непосредственный руководитель, мне сказали, что менеджер всех менеджеров. Она следит за моей деятельностью. Про других точно не знаю, но при мне им также дают распоряжение, как и мне.

Comment: скажу с своей стороны. В больших компаниях бывает "тим лид", EM (engineer manager), Project manager, Техлид, Feature lead (кто ведет какую то большую подзадачу), associate manager. А ещё куча нетехнического персонала - People manager, human manager, happiness manager... Да, очень часто один и тот же человек совмещает в себе многое, но обычно есть два - тим лид и прожект менеджер. И они оба руководителя. Просто у них разные зоны ответственности.   А то что описано в вопросе очень похоже на попытку PIP (performance improvment plan).

Answer (score 7):

Ну в общем то да, обычно джуном (да и вообще разработчиком) управляет тим лид.

То о чем вы пишете крайне напоминает процесс "удушения" нерадивого сотрудника (руководство видимо так решило), по крайней мере, задействованы стандартные инструменты такого "удушения", типа:

- письменная отчетность
- [фото рабочего дня](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F)
- тайминг процессов
- и т.д.

Именно поэтому вам приставлен менеджер, а не слабовольный тим лид.

Следующим, очевидно пойдет вручение вам письменного задания с требованием расписаться в его получении (если откажетесь - то отказ будет заактирован в присутствии 2-х свидетелей). Далее 2-3 таких задания/отказа, аттестация, потом уже увольнение по статье - опыт говорит, что с начала процесса это занимает от месяца до двух.

Я бы вам посоветовал, как действующий [эффективный менеджер](http://www.shern.ru/upravlenie-rabotnikami/effektivnyie-menedzheryi-kto-oni), время от времени вынужденный принимать такие меры, вам пора наверное искать себе работу в другой организации.

P.S. Ничего личного. Просто наблюдения на основе опыта.

Comment: Со многим согласна, что Вы написали. Это просто удушение. Только вот в этой организации всеми программистами управляют менеджеры.

Comment: По сути они не имеют права даже по должностной инструкции мне диктовать способы коммуникации. Там только написано, что я имею право на всю информацию, относящуюся к задаче. Что мне ещё не понравилось, что  о эффективности работы они только составляют из количества задач, хотя они разные бывают по времени. А они лидом не оценены по времени.

Comment: Ещё мне не понятно, зачем так человека удушать. Можно же просто сказать, что не нравится работать с этим человеком. Это же не по-человечески. Это травля.

Answer (score 3):

Мне сильно не хватает места в комментариях, поэтому оставлю ответом.

У нас такая ситуация может тоже быть, когда PM пытается руководить командой, но это в случае дедлайнов, когда не хватает людей и они все заняты на других проектах. Проекты и команды тоже часто меняются. В принципе ничего страшного в этом нет. Единственное у нас нет джунов и младших миддлов, а общение зрелых разработчиков с PM происходит не совсем в плоскости "мне сказали - я исполнил", тут больше совместная работа и решение общих проблем команды. А в случае конфликтов могут и поругаться, но это обычно редкость. За людьми, которые только начинают свой путь, должен присматривать наставник и быть прослойкой между вами и PM. Если этого нет, то в принципе это еще не показатель.

Я бы посоветовал вам обратить внимание сейчас на такие моменты:

1. Если PM дал задание, нужно постараться его исполнить или озвучить проблемы по его исполнению. Пускай даже вам дали установки со сроками, но вы просто должны обосновать их невыполнение, страшного в этом ничего нет.
2. Если вы делаете задачу и возникли вопросы, обращаетесь за помощью и спрашивайте кто вам может помочь (вопрос технический к разрабам или по бизнес-процессам к аналитикам). Это тоже часть работы в команде, что вы не сидите зажавшись в углу и ничего не делаете в случае неуспеха. Такое тоже случается и не только с джунами.
3. Реакция на такие вещи должна быть более-менее адекватной (там могут поругаться, но помощь должна быть оказана). Посмотрите, насколько адекватными будут действия, если у вас возникнут проблемы.
4. У вас должны быть коллеги, с которыми вы общаетесь по рабочим моментам, желательно с code review после выполнения задач.
5. Задачи должны быть вам под силу, может быть и со скрипом, но все-таки выполнимы.
6. Старайтесь не обращать внимания на всякие выходки PM, у них тоже есть свои задачи и свои регламенты работы. Вполне возможно составление всяких характеристик тоже входит в их число. Вас это не должно как правило волновать, чем они занимаются.
7. Следите, чтобы давление не было совсем сильным и градус адеквата сохранялся (мало ли будет ситуация описанная Barmaley).
8. На самом деле работа в таком режиме может сильно повысить навыки, главное не перегореть от эмоциональных качелей, которые любят устраивать некоторые люди.

Ну и имейте ввиду, что мой опыт может очень сильно отличаться от вашего, даже не смотря на схожесть. А советы не подходить к вашим обстоятельствам, но надеюсь хоть чем-то да поможет.

Comment: _У нас такая ситуация может тоже быть_ - было бы неплохо указать, у кого это _у нас_ :)

Comment: @Grundy, очевидно компания-интегратор в которой я работаю, тут несколько групп разработки на проектах. По завершению или сдаче люди перекидываются на другие, начинают реализовывать новые контракты или как пойдет. На двух проектах точно не было изначально тимлидов, они появились спустя пару месяцев - мы не могли закрыть вакансии.